# Custom keywords for if/else/when/etc

Tags: c#

I can't find anything about this subject on google. Is it possible to define your own keyword for keywords like if, else and others? So code like this:

```
if(1 == 1)
{
    //dostuff
}
```

Becomes:

```
myCustomKeyword(1 == 1)
{
    //dostuff
}
```

This way, I can make keywords in a different language for teaching purposes.

Comment: There are no preprocessor macros in C#, so no,there's no built-in way to do that (why would you want to do that anyway?).

Comment: Fork [roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) and add it to your own :)

Comment: Never heard of such a thing in C# for such a basic programming statement. But more important, using `if` instead of your custom keyword wouldn't be _more_ simple and clear in %99.999999 time?

Comment: BTW there are results on google ;)

Comment: I pity the fool that has to maintain your codebase

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). Are you trying to obfuscate code? Or what is the problem you are trying to solve with custom keywords?

Comment: @Sinatr Apparently `if` isn't descriptive enough... lol

Comment: @DGibbs, Maybe OP want to translate `if` into another language? To teach english-not-speaking kids? I dunno...

Comment: Exactly what @Sinatr is saying! Translating some keywords (to Dutch in my case), would make teaching programming just a little bit easier. :-)

Comment: What about do, while, for, foreach, list ... ?

Comment: You seem to intend to teach the wrong things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For teaching purposes you may want to use one of existing software (there should be plenty).There are those what teach logic and programming. Check Games on Steam (e.g. [this](http://store.steampowered.com/app/290020/)). [Here](http://habrahabr.ru/company/ilkfinkom/blog/251583/) is a russian blog (but pictures should give idea) about such games.

To teach `C#` you have to use english. You can name variables in dutch, but kids **must** learn operators and other syntax in english:

```
int grootWaarde = 123456;
Console.WriteLine(MakenGroteKleine(grootWaarde) < grootWaarde ? "Goed" : "Slecht");
```

Comment: I'll just stick with variable names in my desired language then. Danke schön!

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. But [this](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/478968-adding-custom-keywords-c) suggests creating a disposable class and defining variables inside that.

Comment: Is it a new age of NANs (not an answer, link-only answer, etc.)? Link random page and add random words?

Comment: I guess that's my best option then. Thanks for the help!